# How can I include fixtures within mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, fixture

I have used factory girl and now I relealized fxiture is a better design, thus I decided to change to fixture. However, I used mongoid for my database but mongoid doesn't provide fixuter support.

I created my project with command `rails new my-project --skip-active-record` and then include mongoid and factory girl in my Gemfile.

At this condition, how should I include fixture support in my project? I have used the gem 'mongoid-fixture_set', but it doesn't support Rails 5; Then I have used the gem 'fixture_builder', but still not work well.